# MySql-Number of working days in Month or todate with weighted holidays

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate the number of working days in a month, or to current date, using MySQL.

The working days are weighed as such:
Mon-Fri: 1
Sat: 0.5
Sun and Holidays: 0

I have a table, t_holiday, that contains Holidays off (including Sundays, but not Saturdays), as such:

```
_______________________________
|holiday_date | holiday_desc  |
|-------------|---------------|
|2017-12-31   | Sunday Off    | 
|2017-12-25   | Christmas Day |
|2017-12-24   | Sunday Off    |
------------------------------- (and so on)
```

Is this at all possible using mysql? I can probably add Saturdays to the t_holiday if needed.

Comment: The day of the week for a given date can be determined using the appropriate function - so I don’t think there is any need to specifically have the Sundays as “holidays” in your table. You probably want to start with a subselect to check if there is a record in your holidays table for your current revenue date - if so, apply weight 0. If not, check if Sunday or Saturday - if so, 0.5 weight. And else, a weight of 1.

Comment: @Rheine How does your revenue table look like? Can you give us the structure?

Comment: @CBroe So that means I need to have a table of every day in the month-to-date so I can subselect it with the holidays table, then, checking if it's Sunday/Saturday using the SQL function? Would that be how you go with it?

Comment: @Krishnakumar actually the revenue is the result of a query already, joining several tables to get weight * rate, then discount is applied, and some WHERE clause to filter the correct type of revenue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, possible. What you want is
Number of Working Days = Number of Days in Month - Holidays - Saturdays(That are not holidays) * 0.5

The simplest way I can think of to do this is:
1. Yes have a holiday table **t_holiday**
2. Put Saturdays in the holidays table **t_holiday**
3. Put another column **holiday_weight**, where **holiday_weight** for a normal holiday or a Sunday = 1, and **holiday_weight** for a Saturday = 0.5.

Your answer thus would be Number of Working Days = Number of Days in Month - Number(Holiday * weight)

In Sql to say for February that would be:

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY('2015-2-1')) - 
SELECT (SUM(holiday_weight)) FROM t_holiday WHERE YEAR(holiday_date) = my_year AND MONTH(holiday_date) = my_month)
```

If what you want is to-date, then:

```
SELECT DAY(CURDATE()) - 
SELECT (SUM(holiday_weight)) FROM t_holiday WHERE YEAR(holiday_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(holiday_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()))
```

Comment: Thank you, but then there is the matter than the needed amount of days is actually Month-to-Date, not the total working days in a month. So for example, if it's for today (September 7th), it would be 4,5, and tomorrow it would be 5,5, and so on...

Comment: If this is the answer that you were looking for, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Just one more thing -- I'm using HeidiSQL and it doesn't allow me to do the substraction (SELECT DAY(CURDATE()) - SELECT (SUM(holiday_weight)), so I need to save the results separately then subtracts them elsewhere. Is there any workaround for this?